# Android: How to display back arrow in action bar in Activity extended from ListActivity?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity

In activity extended from ActionBarActivity i displaying back arrow in left corner of the action bar using the following statement in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <!-- SETTINGS ACTIVITY --> 
        <activity android:name="com.kwe.smartt.SettingsActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:label="Settings">
                <!-- DISPLAYS BACK ICON IN ACTION BAR --> 
                <meta-data
                  android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                  android:value="com.kwe.smartt.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

But i found, that in activity extended from ListActivity is it not working.

**Question is:**

How can i simple add back arrow in activity extened from ListActivity ?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`, one way would be the following:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

providing the click functionality in:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (android.R.id.home == item.getItemId()) {
        // Do something
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved creating an `activity` like this:

```
public class MyListActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

and then add a `fragment`

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MyListFragment())
                .commit();

}
```

that extend `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`:

```
 public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment
```

I prefer this solution because you can reuse the fragment for a different tablet's layout.